# Как извлечь данные из списка словарей в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Имеется словарь типа:

```
dict = {"count": 2, "index": [{"name": "значение"}, {"id": "значение"}]}
```

Как вывести значения `name` и значение `id`? Пытался вот так:

```
params = dict["index"]
print(params)
```

Но выдаёт ошибку `key error 'index'`, потом почитал и попробовал так:

```
params = dict.get("index")
```

Выдает `None`, хотя если вывести в консоль `print(dict)`  выдаёт `{"count": 2, "index": [{"name": "значение"}, {"id": "значение"}]}`
Нужен код, что бы выводились значения `name` и `id`, заранее благодарен

Comment: Все ли строки в словаре имеют кавычки? Тогда `params = dict["index"]` должен корректно сработать.

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку key error

Comment: в том виде что вы вставили в вопрос dict это не словарь. А не понятно что.
Вот словарь `my_dict = {"count": 2, "index": [{"name": "значение"}, {"id": "значение"}]}`

Comment: Простите, описался, именно в таком виде как вы представили он и выглядит, уже исправил

Comment: возможно у вас в словаре в `"index"` одна из букв русская

Answer (score 2):

Можно извлечь так.

```
my_dict = {"count": 2, "index": [{"name": "значение1"}, {"id": "значение2"}]}

print(*[i[k] for i in my_dict['index'] for k in i])
```

**P.S.**
не стоит называть переменные именами существующих функций. вместо dict используйте что-то вроде my_dict

Comment: Выдаёт такую же ошибку, key error.

Comment: @Neskqik я могу предположить, что если вы выведите type(dict) то увидите что это не словарь а строка

Comment: показывает class dict, это словарь

Comment: @Neskqik тогда вам правильно написали в комментариях, возможно русские буквы

Comment: @Neskqik тогда сначала получите ключи `keys = my_dict.keys()` и потом поставьте my_dict[keys[1]]

Comment: @Neskqik или сразу получить все значения и потом работать с ними `my_dict.values()`

Comment: Спасибо получилось

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin могли бы добавить больше информации в свой ответ, что где делается в коде, ранее была такая же задача, но не знал как правильно написать код, который мог бы работать в одну строку.